# Word for describing the act of praise for self interest

Tags: single-word-requests

I read it about a relationship of two men, where one praised the other extensively for solely his own benefit.

Answer (score 1):

The question requests a verb: "the act of..."

The verb is "flatter". Example:

```
Joe flattered his boss constantly so as to win the coveted promotion.
```

The noun expressing the act of flattering is "flattery", as in

```
Flattery will get you nowhere.
```

In the above sentence the speaker is saying that he/she is immune to flattery.

By the way, in my experience almost no one is immune to flattery. Try flattering your boss, your date, or your banker when applying for credit; you'll be pleased with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who is a self-serving flatterer is a **sycophant**

From https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sycophant:

> A sycophant is a person who tries to win favor from wealthy or influential people by flattering them. Also known as brown-nosers, teacher's pets or suck-ups.
>
> *noun*. a person who tries to please someone in order to gain a personal advantage

Comment: Hi faustus, it's great that you're contributing potentially useful answers, but the system is rightly flagging them for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer, at the very least adding a definition for *sycophant* linked to the source. For further guidance, see [answer].  :-)